# tmux: How can I display the new value for an option, when changing its value through a key-binding?

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

I've created the following key-binding for synchronizing all panes in a window, so that I could e.g. `clear` them all simultaneously:

```
bind C-s setw synchronize-panes \; display-message "█▓░ synchronize"
```

The key-binding simply negate the value of the `synchronize-panes` window option: "on" or "off".

Although, the key-binding works, I'm a little perfectionist, so I'd like the `display-message` to show `"█▓░ synchronize {new-option-value}"`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#{?synchronize-panes,on,off}` ...

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what this does? `?synchronize-panes` is a conditional check for whether it's `on` or `off`?

Comment: Take a look at these https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Formats#comparisons https://man.openbsd.org/tmux.1#FORMATS